# Automation on Windows with Bash like syntax

Tags: windows, bash, shell, automation

Is there a way that we can write automation scripts in bash syntax and run it on Windows host (We can call the executable file .exe of Windows). The Windows batch syntax looks quite complex :D

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Depending on what exactly you want to do, writing a batch file might be trivial enough. Resorting to cygwin would be, at least for me, a much larger commitment.

Comment: @dien when you respond to a comment, use the at sign before their name like I did with your name and the person will be notified about your comment.

Comment: Hi @Joey, I work mostly with Linux and do the network tests with Ixchariot. The test computer only run Windows 7. The job includes start the network test, get the result and configuring the devices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or mingw sys for this.

They are both just BASH implementation available on WinXX (actually they are much more, but you need now only bash).
But there are some differences:

- cygwin uses its own file system hierarchy, with Win drives mapped to a part. subdirs. All related to file names is more unix-style. There are some problems with passing pathnames to Windows programs.
- MinGW is more Windows friendly, file paths are like in Windows, less problems with Windows native programs.

You should try yourself and choose what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You could install cygwin and run bash.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a win32 port of bash. Cygwin is enormous, but native windows bash and a few utilities can be had for a much smaller footprint.

Start with [UnxUtils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/), which includes a `sh` based on `zsh` (it's quite slow, though).

If that's not enough you can get a win32 bash from [some](http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/) [places](http://www.steve.org.uk/Software/bash/), though most are older versions.